# Representing foreign key relationships in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I've been doing a lot of research on Cassandra data models but I'm stuck on how to Cassandra handles metadata(reference) tables.

For example, assuming I have an application within a RDBMS where customers initially register for an account and the application enters the information into a customer entity (customer_id, customer_name). The application also has a transaction table which record the items purchased using the customer_id as a foreign key.

How would I represent these entities in Cassandra starting with the initial registration of the customers and then showing the items purchased by a customer over time (also assuming that a customer may not purchase anything on the day of initial registration)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Important to note, is that in Cassandra you should take a query-based modeling approach.  So when you query the "itemsPurchasedByCustomer" table, what do you usually want to know about the customer?  ID, Name?